# How can I recover deleted files from a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I recently deleted some important files from my USB flash drive by mistake. I've heard that it might be possible to recover them, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Could someone please provide me with guidance on how I can recover these deleted files from my USB flash drive? I'm using a Windows computer, if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can offer!

Comment: This is pretty much an Evergreen Question.  Review the duplicates and go from there.

Comment: Answer linked to provides some pretty outdated answers.